# Google Analytics events: set page url parameter

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Is it possible to set custom page url parameter (named **utmp** in request), when tracking events with Google Analytics?

I have set custom url for tracking pages ['_trackPageview', 'www.my.url.com/...'] But that does not have effect for events.

Comment: you are not supposed to include the full url in there, just the path: ['_trackPageview', '/your-new/path/article.html']

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'page', '/mypage']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

where `/mypage` is your virtual URL. Make sure you set the page before `_trackPageview`.

Answer (score -1):

Read the [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=es).

Comment: Can't find anything related there.